# attaching html from ajax call to shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, shadow-dom

I am trying to make a custom shadow dom element get its HTML from an HTML file stored in a components folder. I can get the HTML just fine like this

```js
$.get( "/component/miniPlayer.html", function( data ) {
    console.log(data)
    root.innerHTML = data;
});
```

but if I then try to do this to put the HTML in the custom element

```js
class miniPlayer extends HTMLElement{
    constructor(){
        super();

        this._root = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this._root.innerHTML = 

        $.get( "/component/miniPlayer.html", function( data ) {
            console.log(data)
            this._root.innerHTML = data;
        });
    }
}

window.customElements.define('mini-player', miniPlayer);
```

I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined`
I have tried it in many different configurations but can't get it to work. is this possible or am i going to have to try something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside your function `function(data) {...}` callback is not the same `this` that the one in the `constructor()` because of the [closure](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp).

You should save the original reference in another variable (ie `that`, or here: `elem`).

```
class miniPlayer extends HTMLElement{
    constructor(){
        super();

        this._root = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this._root.innerHTML = 

        var elem = this
        $.get( "/component/miniPlayer.html", function( data ) {
            console.log(data)
            elem._root.innerHTML = data;
        });
    }
}

window.customElements.define('mini-player', miniPlayer);
```